# How do I load an image from an image path stored in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

On one page I stored the path to an image in a cookie. On the second page, I use the following:

```
<br /><b>Photo:</b> " + $.cookie("image");
```

It just displays the full link on the next page. It is the exact link to the image, so that's good. But how can I make it display an image instead of the path?

Obviously this won't work:

```
<img src="$.cookie("image");
```

But I'm at a loss.

Comment: And why won't that work?

Comment: html = '<br /><b>Photo:</b><img src="' + $.cookie("image") + '">';

Comment: I just get syntax errors doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id or class to image tag and using jQuery to change the image src

HTML

```
<img class="cookieImage" src="" ... >
```

jQuery

```
$('.cookieImage').attr('src', $.cookie("image"));
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this isn't working for me. I put your exact jquery code up in the top, and then I put:
    <img class="cookieImage" src""/> in the html, it doesn't work.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the inline HTML through script:

Suppose yout HTML is structured like:

```
<br /><b>Photo:</b><div id="image_container"></div>
```

Then you could use below script to load that image:

```
var imagePath = $.cookie("image");
$('#image_container').html('<img src="'+ imagePath +'" width=100 height=100/>');
```

Or you could alter the Src attribute of the Image tag.

```
<br /><b>Photo:</b><img id="image_container"></img>
$("#image_container").attr('src', imagePath);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbRDY/)

Comment: This: <br /><b>Photo:</b><img id="image_container"></img>
$("#image_container").attr('src', imagePath);
is both JS and html. So, where does each part go?

Comment: To be honest, I think I'm putting the JS in the wrong locations. Here's what I did. I have jquery and jquery cookie in the code. I know both are working. I then did this:
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var imagePath = $.cookie("image");
 $("#image_container").attr('src', imagePath);
 </script>
    <b>Photo:</b><img id="image_container"></img>
But that isn't working.